# PyCharm: Show .png in markdown cell in Jupyter notebook file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, markdown

I am using PyCharm 2019.2 Professional and I am trying to figure out how to display a .png file within a markdown cell. My file is located in a subfolder called `screenshots`.

I tried the following line of code; however, PyCharm will not display the image. I just see an empty rectangle.

```
![test.png](screenshots/test.png]
```

Comment: It may appear that there's a typo. Try `![test.png](screenshots/test.png)`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. When I go to the URL of the Jupyter notebook server, it displays the image correctly. Why I use matplotlib to plot, those images do appear. I tried using either the shorthand as the OP pointed above or the html tag import image syntax and the same image icon appears. looks like this has been an ongoing issue for a while: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29177

Answer (score 1):

After 4 short years, JetBrains finally fixed this issue in [PyCharm 2021.3 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/). The patch will not be ported to 2021.2 or earlier versions. See this [thread](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29177#focus=Comments-27-5281569.0-0).

If you're using an older PyCharm version and don't feel like updating right now, here is a dirty hack to print images on a grid in your notebook in PyCharm using `matplotlib`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax[0].imshow(plt.imread('iguanas1.png'))
ax[1].imshow(plt.imread('iguanas2.png'))
ax[2].imshow(plt.imread('iguanas3.png'))
```